# AWS S3 and Paperclip not working in production.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I thought this wouldn't be a hard issue to tackle, but I spent enough time now trying to get image uploads to store to my S3 bucket on a Rails application and I keep getting an error.

The application is currently being hosted on Heroku.

From my Heroku logs:

```
Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError (missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION']):
```

Which obviously this would make sense if it were true, however the application works perfectly on my local dev environment. I am storing image uploads on S3 without any issues.

My configuration looks like so in both my production.rb and application.rb files:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => {
        :bucket => ENV["s3_bucket"],
        :access_key_id => ENV["s3_access_key_id"],
        :secret_access_key => ENV["s3_secret_access_key"],
        :s3_region => ENV["s3_region"]
      }
    }
```

I double checked my application.yml folder several times and know the region is defined correctly.

All help would be appreciated. The only thing I can possibly think of is if Heroku can't find my application.yml file or something.

Answer (score 0):

I was right, I forget to send my keys to Heroku.

```
figaro heroku:set -e production
```

That took care of it.